# any good resources about how to implement various image filters in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, graphics

Hi guys I'm new to java graphics and I want to learn how to implement those fancy filters in java i.e the algorithms but I cannot find any comprehensive resources about it. Any good recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: *"hi guys im new to java graphics and i want.."* Are you new to upper case as well?  Please use a capital letter at the start of every sentence and for the word I.  This makes text easier to read.

Comment: You should  understand how those filters works, as algorithms, before caring about Java.

Comment: @leonbloy Yes I do want to know how those algorithms work, but I cannot find good materials about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following resource to be very handy:

http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/

I'm not sure what you are actually going for (comprehensive?), but the above got me up the curve quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks Kevin I found that website too. Besides those filters it introduces I also want to know how filters like Orton or Urbane work.

Comment: Have you read this?  http://pcin.net/update/2006/11/01/the-orton-effect-digital-photography-tip-of-the-week/  - again, not sure if you are looking for algorithmic details, or just "what is the general idea behind filter XYZ".  It sounds like Orton effect can be had by using a combination of Gaussian blur and some sort of blending.

Comment: I read that too!That'd be great if you can provide algorithmic details. But it is also ok if I can know what operations I should do to achieve certain effect, say to achieve Orton I need to do Gaussian blur first and then overexposure, ...

Comment: Sorry - you've now exceeded my knowledge of photographic image processing.  The image processing work I do is with scanned documents - black and white, no grayscale.  If I were researching this, I'd start with wikipedia, find related resources (for example, here's how to achieve the Orton effect in Gimp: http://www.gimpforphotos.com/tutorials-beginner/orton-effect.html ) - then figure out which filters you *do* have are equivalent to what Gimp is doing, then give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

The best resource I know of for dealing with Images in Java is the book ***Filthy Rich Clients***

http://filthyrichclients.org/

There is very detailed and didatic info on image filters of all kinds. A must read to anybody working with the Java graphics stack.

Comment: Thanks Victor! If I cannot find any tutorials online, I'll grab one!